# oembed - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ubuntu, soundcloud, digital-ocean

I have two identical Ubuntu servers, and when trying to access this example:

curl "http://soundcloud.com/oembed" -d 'format=json' -d 'url=http://soundcloud.com/barefoot-wade/big-empty-rooms' -L -s -v -o /dev/null

On one server, I get a proper 200 OK response, but on the other, I get "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"

I have tried finding the difference using strace, ltrace, and tcpdump, but I cannot find any differences that should be making a difference.

Is there something else I should be looking for, or is the soundcloud.com server blocking me for some reason?

edit: It could be that Soundcloud is blocking DigitalOcean ip addresses. I've found loose evidence that they have done this with other VPS providers as well. Seems to me that I should be getting some kind of 403 instead of a 500 if such was the case..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was started about two weeks ago me too. I asked same question at SO [ [SoundCloud API return error 500](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709589/soundcloud-api-return-error-500) ] and still have no answer. SoundCloud support not responding or answering by template like "here read FAQ and leave us out". At SoundCloud community no answer. status.soundcloud.com silent about this, but the problem is not single case and I'm tracking news for error 500 and see how count of cases growing up.

My servers at Azure [Netherlands location].

A solution of this problem is to use proxy to fake your real server IP address.